# Is it a good idea to train a face classifier (Conv NN) without aligning faces?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a set of images of people coming into a store captured from a camera pointing at the door.  I have about 100s of faces from which I have to take out all the staff faces that work at the store.

I thought of preparing a training set with staff faces and customer faces labelled separately.  Is it necessary to perform face alignment before feeding the images to the CNN for training?  What if we just give it the raw images.  The raw images cover - the hair, neck and the whole face of the person.

Can you suggest me how I can circumvent the task of face alignment in case it is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

This will work but alignment will give you better results faster. Be sure to use data augmentation that allows for translation and cropping.